# VSCode can't find scss import in Svelte component if path contains $lib alias

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, svelte

Vite preprocess can handle $lib aliases inside component styles.
I would like to use

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '$lib/styles/mixins';

  ...
</styles>
```

which works as expected.

But VSCode with Svelte extension doesn't handle these import and show annoying lint error

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
```

Is there any way to fix it or mute error?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this issue happens in a monorepo.

To work around this problem, define a custom scss importer in the `vitePreprocess` preprocessor.

Your `svelte.config.js` file should look something like this:

```js
import path from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

const dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
export default {
  preprocess: vitePreprocess({
    style: {
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            importer: [
              (url) => {
                if (url.startsWith('$lib')) {
                  return {
                    file: url.replace(/^\$lib/, path.join(dirname, 'src', 'lib')),
                  };
                }
                return url;
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }),

  // other options
};
```

Comment: Preprocess can handle it, that's not issue. Issue is lack of support in VSCode extension.

Comment: @farincz I know. This was the case for me as well. The code snippet i provided solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

that is because using a relative path in `prependData`

```
preprocess: preprocess({
        scss: {
            // prependData: 'use "../styles/functions";'
            prependData: '@use "src/styles/functions";'
        }
    }),
```